# 'Hybrid' scoring (Drools + Java)

Tags: optaplanner

I am basically trying to implement some kind of hybrid (drools + java) scoring for OptaPlanner.
Most of the rules are drools, however, I can perform some of the constraint checking for some rules much faster, if I do it in java.
So, after a solution change, the drools scorer would run, my Java scorer would be invoked which would then modify the result of the drools calculation.
The interface AbstractIncrementalScoreCalculator looks promising.
(I am not trying to implement full incremental scoring, just some performance imrovements.)

Any has some hints? Am I on the right track? Anyone got hints/suggestions?

Thanks
Tibor

**Update1:**
So, based on Geoffrey hint below, I did the following:

So, I have modified ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig, so that now instead of throwing an excpetion if both an incremental and a drools scorer is configured, it creates a HybridScoreDirector. (using a modified version a LegacyDroolsScoreDirectorFactory, which injects the IncrementalScoreCalculator instance into the HybridScoreDirector.) The HybridScoreDirector itself is a modified DroolsScoreDirector, where the calculateScore calls the calculateScore method of the incremental scorer, after drools scoring has been performed. The interface methods (afterVariableChanged, beforeVariableChanged are also invoked from the ScoreDirector, although I am not using them in my tests. Currently I am achieving around 1200 steps/sec on my laptop using Late Acceptance.

Answer (score 0):

It can currently only use 1 ScoreDirector: drools xor inc java xor easy java. That is a dead end.

Calling java code from drools is possible, but the modified notifications need to work in your favor... For example: Putting an InverseRelationShadowVariable on shadow entity Employee can make that happen if you want to do a calculation over all ShiftAssignments of an employee.

Comment: I did not look into it yet in detail, but I was thinking to modify ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig and have a modified DroolsScoreDirector, where I could hook my code into the afterEntityAdded etc. methods. I would check your suggestion, as it sounds much easier. Following that route, would I be able to modify the score from the notification? Thanks

Comment: that could work, try it out. If it works well, open a jira to support it out of the box and clearly motivate why it's better